# How to code for GPS Application?

Tags: iphone

Hi i m going to build up a GPS based application in which i want to locate the place with altitude and latitude of a person who is using GPS application.

Please suggest me tips how to start and how to code for that.

Aman Gupta

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Core Location framework [reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/).